# Arrange and rezise all images in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm making a presentation with only images and captions from events as a slideshow, one slide per event. One slide can contain 2-8 images from the same event.

I would like to be able to rezise and arrange all images in one slide or the whole presentation. But I can't figure out how to find or select all images.

I know how to insert a shape of a certain size, but I don't know how to find the images already inserted, and resize them.

```
function plassering() {
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[6];
var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE);
shape.setLeft(14).setTop(14).setWidth(690).setHeight(510).setRotation(0);
Logger.log('Left: ' + shape.getLeft()
                + 'pt; Top: ' + shape.getTop()
                + 'pt; Width: ' + shape.getWidth()
                + 'pt; Height: ' + shape.getHeight()
                + 'pt; Rotation: ' + shape.getRotation() + '\u00B0.');
}
```

The caption should be on top av all the images.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to resize the existing image on the slide. Is my understanding correct? When you can know the method for resizing one image, can you do this for all images? By the way, what is the meaning of ``The caption should be on top av all the images.``? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Yes, you understood correct. I need to know two things:
1. How to rezise and rearrange an existing object.
2. How to loop through all the images in a slide, and resize and reaarange them.

Comment: The caption is a text box with a description of the event.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the rearrangement you think? For example, when each image is converted to the small size by 50 %, the spaces between each image become large. In this case, you want to also convert the spaces to 50 %. Is my understanding correct? And also, in order to help to understand your situation, can you provide a sample slides you want to use for this situation? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Here is a test:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1nf0qH8Q91-6WZSZYWLiqeCjoaxSTbB29eKE3UuB41as/edit?usp=sharing

All images should be the width of the slide, stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw the shared slides. For this slide, what do you want to do? I thought that this is the sample before the processing. So can you provide the sample after the processing? And I couldn't understand about ``All images should be the width of the slide, stacked on top of each other.``. Can you explain the detail? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me! :-)
This is a sample of how I wish it to be after I run the code: All images on a slide are stacked on top of eachother and they are the same witdh. The purpose of this: Other people will add the images from an event to a slide, one slide per event. How the images look on the slide is not important. When all the people have added their images I wil tidy up the presentation by running this code and all the images will be of the same width. Think of it as a box with notebooks in. All the notebooks are a little smaller than the box and stacked on top of eachother

Comment: About ``All images on a slide are stacked on top of eachother and they are the same width.``, I could confirm that in your shared slides, several images are put to a slide with the same width. For this situation, can I ask you about "Arrange and rezise all images"? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! This is for the current slide, but I guess I may do the same for all the slides, one at a time.

```
function rearrangeImages() {
  //Select current page
  var currentPage = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
  var slide = currentPage;
  //Get all the images of CurrentPage
  var pageElements = slide.getImages();
  //For each image, change the size and position
  for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    pageElements[i].select(true);
    var image = pageElements[i];
    var imgWidth = image.getWidth();
    var newWidth = 690; 
    var imgHeight = image.getHeight();
    var forhold = imgHeight/imgWidth;
    var newHeight = forhold*newWidth;
    image.setLeft(14).setTop(14).setWidth(newWidth).setHeight(newHeight).setRotation(0);
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
   // ui.alert (imgWidth);
    pageElements[i].select(false);
  }
}
```